# Website visitors from database on jvectormap?

Tags: php, mysql, database, jvectormap

How to import my visitor  data from mysql database on php page to browse it on jvectormap?
This is my js code:

```
//jvectormap data
   $(".knob").knob();
var visitorsData = {
    "US": 398, //USA
    "SA": 400, //Saudi Arabia
    "CA": 1000, //Canada
    "DE": 500, //Germany
    "FR": 760, //France
    "CN": 300, //China
    "AU": 700, //Australia
    "BR": 600, //Brazil
    "IN": 800, //India
    "GB": 320, //Great Britain
    "RU": 3000 //Russia
};
```

Comment: 1) run query 2) fetch data from query 3) json_encode query results 4) stuff json-encoded array into your web page 4) ??? 5) profit

Comment: @MarkB isn't there some magic code on the interwebs that will skip 1-4 and jump right to 5. haha